# How can I bind the data from a dynamically created table to the model?

Tags: angularjs

I am having trouble figuring out a good way to bind the data in this dynamically created table. I'm having trouble, both referencing the data for the original value of the input field, and I am having trouble updating the model after a change is made to the input field.

I've tried these:

```
<input type="text" value="{{set.date}}" ng-change="change(this.value)" />
<input type="text" ng-model="{{set.time}}" ng-change="change(this.value)" />
<input type="text" ng-value="{{set.exercise}}" ng-change="change(this.value)" />
```

[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/xZ8AqJJlUMxQOxoitEsh?p=preview)

Do I need to create a unique key and pair it to each object in the model array so that I can pass it though to the `change()` method?

I'd like to avoid creating another level of keys in my model if possible.

Comment: Two of those won't actually work, as should be evident by the error in the console in your plunker: `Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'ngModel', required by directive 'ngChange', can't be found!`

Comment: you don't actually need to use `ng-change` at all for a simple auto updating table; `ng-model` works all by itself as a two way binding.  see http://plnkr.co/edit/ZYCiQ5qkbv3NqFD6eu9O?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use ng-modle like this `ng-model="set.time"` You don't need the curly braces to interpolate the expression because ng-model itself is a directive, it evaluates the expression for you. 
Here is an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/QHnhRFpoc4ZiX2BZcZwm?p=preview)